# UtilisateurResourceIT.findAllJames:171 JSON path "$.[*].id" Expected: a collection containing <1258> but: was empty

Tags: java, spring, jpa, integration-testing, mockmvc

I am working on a spring boot app, when I run integration tests I got this error

> ```
> [ERROR] Failures:
> [ERROR]   UtilisateurResourceIT.findAllJames:171 JSON path "$.[*].id"
> Expected: a collection containing <1258>
>      but: was empty
> [INFO]
> [ERROR] Tests run: 121, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
> ```

any help to solve please !

here is my UtilisateurResourceIT.java

```
..
@Test
    @Transactional
    void getAllUtilisateursCalledJames() throws Exception {
        // Initialize the database
        utilisateurRepository.saveAndFlush(utilisateur);

        // Get all the utilisateurList
        restUtilisateurMockMvc
            .perform(get("/api/utilisateurCalledJames" + "?sort=id,desc"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].id").value(hasItem(utilisateur.getId().intValue())))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].nomUtilisateur").value(hasItem(DEFAULT_NOM_UTILISATEUR)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].prenom").value(hasItem(DEFAULT_PRENOM)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].nom").value(hasItem(DEFAULT_NOM)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].dateInscription").value(hasItem(DEFAULT_DATE_INSCRIPTION.toString())))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].password").value(hasItem(DEFAULT_PASSWORD)));
    }
..
```

my UtilisateurResource.java

```
 /**
     * {@code GET  /utilisateurCalledJames} : get all the utilisateurs Called James.
     *
     * @param pageable the pagination information.
     * @return the {@link ResponseEntity} with status {@code 200 (OK)} and the list of utilisateurs in body.
     */
    @GetMapping("/utilisateurCalledJames")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Utilisateur>> getAllUtilisateursCalledJames(
        @org.springdoc.api.annotations.ParameterObject Pageable pageable
    ) {
        log.debug("REST request to get a page of Utilisateurs");
        Page<Utilisateur> page = utilisateurRepository.findAllJames(pageable);
        HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest(), page);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(page.getContent());
    }
```

and my Query request in UtilisateurRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface UtilisateurRepository extends JpaRepository<Utilisateur, Long> {
    @Query(value = "select * from utilisateur where nom='james'", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Utilisateur> findAllJames(Pageable pageable);
}
```

Comment: Try $.[0].id instead of $.[*].id because you want to match the first element

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Thank you for the answer! unfortunately it generates thhis error `No value at JSON path "$.[0].id"`. btw someone told me that the error comes from the sql query it return nom='james' but in UtilisateurResourceIT DEFAULT_NOM = 'AAAAAAAAAA'. I could't add the whole class because stackoverflow tells me that my question is mostly code .. so here is the whole class https://github.com/hamaarouf/userAuth/blob/main/src/test/java/com/mycompany/myapp/web/rest/UtilisateurResourceIT.java

Comment: findAllJames return no content